# Strange behavior of titleView that does not appear until back button is pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In `viewDidLoad` I have a UINavigationBar with a custom background implemented in the following way:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nav_bg_image]] atIndex:100];
```

On the top of the stack (call it `RVC`) I have the following complete code:

```
UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:navbar_image_logo]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nav_bg_image]] atIndex:100];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:logoView];
[logoView release];
```

This works brilliantly. However, when I push a new `VC` on the stack and use the same code in `viewDidLoad`

```
UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:navbar_image_logo]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nav_bg_image]] atIndex:1];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:logoView];
[logoView release];
UIBarButtonItem *hButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Filters" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(filtersAction)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = hButton;
[hButton release];
```

Neither the "Filters" button nor the titleView imageView appears. However, I know the filters button has been added to the UI because if I click in the area that it is supposed to appear, the action is performed.

Furthermore, when I drill down to a detail view `DVC` and go back, all of the sudden the titleView (logoView) appears!

I suspect that this is some sort of memory issue but I have not been able to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mention of the issue you are having with ordering at iDev Recipes [How do iPhone apps Instagram/Reeder/DailyBooth implement custom NavigationBars with variable width back buttons?](http://idevrecipes.com/category/uinavigationcontroller/)

Basically you are adding your background in the wrong way.

**Support only iOS 5**
Implement a method like `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:`

**Support Older iOS's + iOS 5**

1. Subclass `UINavigationBar` and implement the `drawRect`

   ```
   //.h
   @interface CustomNavigationBar : UINavigationBar
   @end

   //.m
   @implementation CustomNavigationBar

   - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
   {
       UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"BackgroundImage"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
       [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
   }

   @end
   ```
2. To get a `UINavigationController` to use your subclass you need to create it using a xib.

[image]

---

If you have set everything up in code then you will still need to use a nib to do this.
The nib I use has no `File's Owner` and only contains a `Navigation Controller` that is configured to use my `CustomNavigationBar` and has no `viewControllers`

In this case I set this up in code like this:

```
// Load my nib with only a Navigation Controller and custom navigationBar
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomNavigationController" owner:nil options:nil];

// The only top level object will be my navigationController
UINavigationController *navigationController = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

// Push a view controller to be the rootViewController
[navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:NO];
```

Then present this controller however I normally would. The controller/window that presents it will take the required retain on the `UINavigationController`

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the method `insertSubView:atIndex:` looks suspicious.  Do you really have 100 subviews in that view?

Comment: No, originally I had it at index:0 but I wanted (For debugging purposes) to make sure that it was not superceding another view since it takes up the whole view. - It didn't work with index:0,1,or 100.

Comment: You can only insert at valid indexes. If you want an added subview to appear "in front", just use `-addSubview:` (i.e. the index parameter is the same as zIndex)